# PHP openssl_encrypt security

Tags: php, encryption

I have been able to encrypt and decrypt strings using the following functions that were given as examples in the PHP docs:

```
function encryptText($plaintext) {
  $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
  $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;

  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
  $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options, $iv);
  $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary = true);
  $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);
  return $ciphertext;
}

function decryptText($ciphertext) {
  $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
  $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
  $sha2len = 32;

  $cyphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext);
  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
  $iv = substr($cyphertext_dec, 0, $ivlen);
  $hmac = substr($cyphertext_dec, $ivlen, $sha2len);
  $ciphertext_raw = substr($cyphertext_dec, $ivlen + $sha2len);
  $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options, $iv);
  $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary = true);

  // timing attack safe comparison
  if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
    return $decrypted;
  }
}
```

However, the encrypted string that is returned from encryptText, can simply be decrypted by anyone using the decryptText function, making me wonder, what is the point of encryption?

Are there some ways I can add to these functions to make them more secure?

Comment: I don't get your question - why not keep the cipher secret, as usual in your encryption?

Comment: Also, why not use any of the existing libraries (like phpseclib) to avoid these low-level calls?

Comment: Decrypted by anyone? The decrypting side must know the key (`$key`).

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch the $key variable in the example.  Since I hadn't set it in my experiments, apparently an empty string was used?  Are you saying I can set $key to any string, and just be sure to use it on both ends?

Comment: Yes, the `$key` is the shared passphrase, the argument name for `$key` is passphrase, strange that the documentation when with `$key` since passphrase is more common when talking about something that might be shared in an encrypt/decrypt scenario.

Comment: I came upon openssl_private_encrypt, but if I am understanding it correctly, that would just accomplish the same thing as sharing the same $key on both ends in this example, no?

Comment: That's how AES works, as this is a symmetric encryption algortihm

Comment: AES uses keys that must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes in size. E.g. for AES-128-CBC a 16 bytes key must be applied. Too long keys are truncated by PHP, too short keys are padded with 0x00 values. The key must be used on both sides.

Comment: `openssl_private_encrypt()` is a low level function for signing, not encrypting, and uses asymmetric instead of symmetric encryption.

Comment: Ah, so in my first experiments, my key was a string of 16 0x00 values :-) I am assuming PHP is reading each character as 1 byte, correct? (assuming only using ASCII chars.)

Comment: If you did not specify a key, a key consisting of 0x00 values was applied. Ultimately, the encoding determines how the characters map to bytes and thus also the number of bytes. E.g. for UTF-8 the 1:1 relation would apply for ASCII characters.

Comment: Question: Does openssl_encrypt implement methods to help mitigate the risk of side-channel attacks?

Comment: Symmetric encryption keys are not readable text but arbitrary [random bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), so text encoding is irrelevant. If they are stored in text configuration files they are typically base64 or hex encoded. For anything with less entropy than random bytes use a [key derivation function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to produce a suitable key.